# What is the practical use of an io! block in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

What would be an example scenario where an io! block would be used in Clojure? I am having troubles understanding its purpose.

Comment: Never used it, but it seems to be a way of enforcing that a function/code isn't used in a transaction.

Comment: Interesting question … I did a quick search of the mailing list, found [one thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/ZZP93tVmot4/DoDBAlDrHmYJ) and [another](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/TAhNp7rb2Go/Kij920UDKbwJ), and especially [the thread in which it was introduced](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/JRRegOOwohE/3gWZjmWClpUJ) (and the [commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/c5e8c6f06292fab26d29cb951d8400394e0f8258)).

Comment: Thanks @glts very useful links. I think the following two answers summarise it well: "I think It stops other code to wrap around the code with the explicit io! call.
Its declarative way of saying: I am doing io! DONT USE me inside a dosync." and "The point is to mark side-effecting code so that you can't accidentally use it in a transaction."

Answer (score 5):

It's a part of the STM system for [ensuring that code related to IO is not used inside STM transactions.](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/io!) Since clojure will retry a transaction if another thread commits contradictory data while a transaction is running, any IO produced by that transaction would be bogus because it represents a state of memory that could be discarded.

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2485), you'll see that it just throws an exception if a transaction is in progress, otherwise it executes the body as normal.

Comment: This is helpful but abstract. An example scenario where you'd actually use it: say you are writing a package with some functions that do IO, some known to the user, some unknown to the user.  use `(io! & body)` for in all of these to throw and error if they're used in an unsafe way (ie within transactions)

Comment: been working in clojure for the last seven years professionally, and have never seen it used, so no common examples come to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I got my head around it after all. As mentioned on a comment above: "The point is to mark side-effecting code so that you can't accidentally use it in a transaction" summarises it well for me